# Загрузка данных из java файла в таблицу javaFX

Tags: javafx

Есть java файл

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 5;
    int m = (int) Math.pow(2, n);

    int[][] x = new int[m][];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        x[i] = generateBitsArray(i, n);
    }

    printHeader(n);
    print(x);
}

public static int[] generateBitsArray(int value, int len) {
    String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(value);
    char[] digits = bin.toCharArray();
    int[] x = new int[len];

    for (int i = len - digits.length, j = 0; i < len; i++, j++) {
        x[i] = Integer.parseInt("" + digits[j]);
    }

    return x;
}

public static void print(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%-3d", arr[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void print(int[][] matrix) {
    for (int i = 0, len = matrix.length; i < len; i++) {
        print(matrix[i]);
    }
}

public static void printHeader(int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        System.out.printf("x%d ", i + 1);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Как полученные данные (переменные с 0 и 1) загрузить в таблицу javaFX ?

Comment: В чём заключается вопрос?

Comment: Я не могу понять как эти данные(переменные с 0 и 1) загрузить в таблицу в javaFX. Или как связать их.

Comment: Отредактируйте ваш вопрос воспользовавшись [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/665799/edit). Заодно поправте формат кода.

Comment: попробуйте добавить в вопрос [mcve]